# itemize in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

I'm creating a Persian presentation using xepersian. How can I change blue squares in below code to numbers and make them print in the left of the text? Also I want world be shown properly and inorder. Any answer is highly appreciated:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=eastern]{farsi}
\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=arab]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\farsifontsf[Script=arab]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{سیب}
\begin{itemize}\raggedleft
\item it is not ok
 \item they printed reversly!
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Also I want world be shown properly and inorer"

Comment: "Also I want world be shown properly and inorDER. When I run the code, order of words disappear. They don't print in order @samcarter

Comment: You can edit your question, to fix the typos, samcarter was concerned about.

Comment: I did it now @Jan

Comment: you have set the default language to be Farsi, and never specified English, so the typesetting direction is naturally wrong for English.

Comment: You are right, But the question is how to solve the problem. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: use the polyglossia commands to switch languages. `\textenglish` probably for short sections or  `\setotherlanguage{english}` in the preamble and then `\begin{english}...\end{english}` around english bits